# How do I change the Arm64 chars to 92x?

Tags: dataframe

I've been looking to change the arm64 chars to 92x but don't know where to start?

The current arm64 code is:

x93kxke | i23kx931

I want to convert it to 92x

Comment: Please check if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Sha256

SHA-2 (Secure Hash Algorithm 2) is a set of cryptographic hash functions designed by the United States National Security Agency (NSA) and first published in 2001.[3][4] They are built using the Merkle–Damgård construction, from a one-way compression function itself built using the Davies–Meyer structure from a specialized block cipher.

SHA-2 includes significant changes from its predecessor, SHA-1. The SHA-2 family consists of six hash functions with digests (hash values) that are 224, 256, 384 or 512 bits: SHA-224, SHA-256, SHA-384, SHA-512, SHA-512/224, SHA-512/256. SHA-256 and SHA-512 are novel hash functions computed with eight 32-bit and 64-bit words, respectively. They use different shift amounts and additive constants, but their structures are otherwise virtually identical, differing only in the number of rounds. SHA-224 and SHA-384 are truncated versions of SHA-256 and SHA-512 respectively, computed with different initial values. SHA-512/224 and SHA-512/256 are also truncated versions of SHA-512, but the initial values are generated using the method described in Federal Information Processing Standards (FIPS) PUB 180-4.

SHA-2 was first published by the National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) as a U.S. federal standard (FIPS). The SHA-2 family of algorithms are patented in US patent 6829355.[5] The United States has released the patent under a royalty-free license.[6]

Currently, the best public attacks break preimage resistance for 52 out of 64 rounds of SHA-256 or 57 out of 80 rounds of SHA-512, and collision resistance for 46 out of 64 rounds of SHA-256.[1][2]